# PhoneGap 3.6.3 error install in windows

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

could someone help me?

Following error when installing the android platform on my project.

It is the first time I use the new versions of phonegap.

could someone help me, please?

```
C:\example>cordova platform add android
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.3
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.3.
tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.3.
tgz
Creating android project...

C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_mod
ules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must
fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\l
ib\check_reqs.js:158:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\p
ackage\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-
android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\co
rdova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\n
ode_modules\q\q.js:821:14
    at flush (C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\packag
e\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
Error: C:\Users\dario\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\c
reate.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\dario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add Android as a platform if you not install Android SDK first.

> Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH.
>   You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.

Once Android SDK is installed, you need to set environment variables for Android SDK.
Look for "\sdk\tool" and "\sdk\platform-tools".
In my case i have it under Eclipse folder because i installed Eclipse ADT with Android SDK included.